# Select only those records where all linked records fulfill a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a classical 1:n relation between two tables as given below:
[image]

I need to select only those customers where 'NOT OrderDate IS NULL' for all their orders. I started with

```
SELECT Customers.Id, Customers.LastName
  FROM Customers, Orders
 WHERE Customers.Id = Orders.CustomerId AND NOT Orders.OrderDate IS NULL AND ...
```

and wanted to build further with 'FOR ALL' but failed.

I tried the suggestions given in the answers but none gave the correct results.

Here is my workaround with two temp tables as shown below:

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (
    Id int,
    CountA   int
)

DECLARE @TableB TABLE (
    Id int,
    CountB   int
)

INSERT INTO @TableA (Id, CountA)
SELECT        Customers.Id, COUNT(Orders.Id)
FROM            Customers INNER JOIN
                         Orders ON Customers.Id = Orders.CustomerId
GROUP BY Customers.ID

INSERT INTO @TableB (Id, CountB)
SELECT        Customers.Id, COUNT(Orders.Id)
FROM            Customers INNER JOIN
                         Orders ON Customers.Id = Orders.CustomerId
WHERE (NOT Orders.OrderDate IS NULL)                     
GROUP BY Customers.ID

Select tA.Id 
FROM  @TableA tA INNER JOIN  @TableB tB on tA.Id = tB.Id
WHERE tA.CountA = tB.CountB
```

Both temp tables differ only in that respect that the first selects the group count without a condition in Orders and the second temp selects them with a condition. Then joining the two temp tables where CountA = CountB gives only those customers where all related Orders fulfill the condition.

If someone finds a more elegant way, please let me know.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: This is just a simplified example of two related tables (A, B). But generally I need to check if there are any records in table A where all related records in table B fulfill a condtion. Then these records of table A I need to list.

Comment: OK do the below suggestions work for you?

Comment: I tried below suggestions, but none gave me the correct results. So I solved it by working with two temp tables -> see my edited post

Answer (score 2):

> Any suggestions how to tackle this?

In cases like this, you need to think not of finding the records where all the related records meet a condition.

Instead, think of finding all the records WHERE there does NOT EXIST a related record that breaks the condition.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to write this query, is with [ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/all-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT Customers.Id, Customers.LastName
FROM Customers
WHERE '2000-01-01' < ALL(SELECT OrderDate FROM Orders WHERE Orders.CustomerId = Customers.Id)
```

You could also write it as a group query on the orders table, something like

```
WITH CustomerOrderDateRange(CustomerId, MinOrderDate, MaxOrderDate) AS (
  SELECT CustomerId, MIN(OrderDate), MAX(OrderDate)
  FROM Orders
  GROUP BY CustomerId
)
SELECT Customers.Id, Customers.LastName
FROM Customers
JOIN CustomerOrderDateRange
  ON Customers.Id = CustomerOrderDateRange.CustomerId
WHERE
  CustomerOrderDateRange.MinOrderDate > '2000-01-01'
```

I think this is cleaner if you need multiple criteria, for example a max date range as well.

Comment: When did `ALL` become a part of SQL Server syntax?

Comment: @TabAlleman As it says in the documentation I linked, in SQL server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Just locate the records you want to exclude from it, and put in a not in clause

```
 select *
 from Customers
 where Customers.Id not in (
   SELECT Customers.Id
   FROM Customers 
   join Orders on Customers.Id = Orders.CustomerId
   WHERE Orders.OrderDate < '2000-01-01'
   group by Customers.Id 
 )
```

Comment: You should use `not exists` instead of  `not in`